# String concatenation compliant with Symfony2 coding style standard

Tags: php, symfony

How could I write a long string like the following to be Symfony2 CS standard compliant?

```
$str = 'A very long line that' .
    'spans in multiple lines';
```

Now I'm getting a "Concat operator must not be surrounded by spaces" error. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space before the dot ?

Comment: @smarber I've tried with and without the space... same error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using something like that:

```
$str  = 'A very long line that';
$str .= 'spans in multiple lines';
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/651

```
<rule ref="Squiz.Strings.ConcatenationSpacing">
   <properties>
       <property name="ignoreNewlines" value="1"/>
   </properties>
</rule>
```